# Mysql insere valor diferente na colula de referência passado na query

Tags: sql

Olá, quando executo um `insert` em qualquer tabela que tem a coluna users_id que faz referência a tabela `glpi_users`, qualquer valor maior que 126 o banco insere o valor 127, por exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO `glpi_plugin_actualtime_tasks` (`tasks_id`, `actual_begin`, `users_id`)
  VALUES ('8926', '2019-06-27 19:25:22', '373');
```

O valor que é inserido é 127 e não 373, não faço ideia do que seja!

```
Servidor: Localhost via UNIX socket
Tipo de servidor: MariaDB
Versão do servidor: 10.1.40-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
Versão do protocolo: 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O tipo de dado `TINYINT` ocupa um único byte e portanto pode representar valores inteiros de -128 a 127. É impossível armazenar o inteiro 373 em um `TINYINT`.

Comment: É isso mesmo! Deu certo! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

O campo users_id deve estar como NUMERO INTEIRO com auto incremento. Desta maneira, ele sempre irá usar o próximo número em novos registros.

Comment: Na verdade a coluna users_id não está como auto increment ela está como tinyint not null, apenas é uma coluna para referenciar id da tabela glpi_users que é auto increment do tipo int.

Comment: CREATE TABLE atak_glpi.glpi_plugin_actualtime_tasks (
  id INT(1) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tasks_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  actual_begin DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  actual_end DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  users_id TINYINT(11) NOT NULL,
  actual_actiontime INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
AUTO_INCREMENT = 53,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 334,
CHARACTER SET utf8,
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE atak_glpi.glpi_plugin_actualtime_tasks 
  ADD INDEX tasks_id(tasks_id);

ALTER TABLE atak_glpi.glpi_plugin_actualtime_tasks 
  ADD INDEX users_id(users_id);